# Changing button style after interaction using Discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a rock paper scissors game using buttons, however, I'm new to 13v and this is my first time using buttons, I wanted to make it where when the user clicks the button of their choice, that button turns green aka its style turns into "SUCCESS" but it's not updating on the Discord API, seems like styles aren't Read-only so, does anyone have any idea why is this happening?

My code:

```js
const db = require('quick.db')
const { MessageEmbed, MessageButton, MessageActionRow } = require('discord.js')
const { BOT_PREFIX } = require('../config')
const commandName = 'rockpaperscissor'


module.exports = client => {
    client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
        if (message.author.bot) return
        if (!message.content.startsWith(BOT_PREFIX)) return

        const command = message.content.split(' ')
        const args = message.content.substring(1).split(' ')

        if (command.toString().toLowerCase().replace(BOT_PREFIX, '').startsWith(commandName) || command.toString().toLowerCase().replace(BOT_PREFIX, '').startsWith('rps')) {
            const buttonRow1 = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('rock-RPS')
                .setLabel('ROCK')
                .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                .setDisabled(false),
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('paper-RPS')
                .setLabel('PAPER')
                .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                .setDisabled(false),
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('scissors-RPS')
                .setLabel('SCISSORS')
                .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                .setDisabled(false)
            )
            
            const filter = (interaction) => {
                if (!interaction.isButton) return
                if (interaction.customId.includes('-RPS'))
                if (interaction.user.id === message.author.id) return true;
                interaction.reply({ content: 'This game isn\'t for you.' })
            }

            const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
                filter,
                max: 1,
            })

            message.reply({ content: 'Testing!', components: [buttonRow1] })
      
            const choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
            let botChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];

            let userBalance =  parseInt(await db.fetch(`${message.author.id}.balance`))
            if (userBalance == null) await db.set(`${message.author.id}.balance`, 0)
            function randomNumber(min, max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min+1)+min);   
            }
            let reward1 = randomNumber(153, 535)
            let reward2 = randomNumber(553, 1460)
    
            collector.on('end', async (buttonInteraction) => {
                const interaction = buttonInteraction.first();
                const success = new MessageButton(buttonInteraction.component).setStyle("SUCCESS");
                await interaction.deferReply({
                    ephemeral: false
                })
                interaction.reply('Please wait...')
                if (interaction.customId == 'rock-RPS') {
                    interaction.update({ components: [new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
                        new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('rock-RPS')
                        .setLabel('ROCK')
                        .setStyle('SUCCESS')
                        .setDisabled(true),
                        new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('paper-RPS')
                        .setLabel('PAPER')
                        .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                        .setDisabled(true),
                        new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('scissors-RPS')
                        .setLabel('SCISSORS')
                        .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                        .setDisabled(true))] 
                    })
                } else if (interaction.customId == 'paper-RPS') {
                    interaction.update({ components: [new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
                        new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('rock-RPS')
                        .setLabel('ROCK')
                        .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                        .setDisabled(true),
                        new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('paper-RPS')
                        .setLabel('PAPER')
                        .setStyle('SUCCESS')
                        .setDisabled(true),
                        new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('scissors-RPS')
                        .setLabel('SCISSORS')
                        .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                        .setDisabled(true))] 
                    })
                } else if (interaction.customId == 'scissors-RPS') {
                    interaction.update({ components: [new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
                        new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('rock-RPS')
                        .setLabel('ROCK')
                        .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                        .setDisabled(true),
                        new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('paper-RPS')
                        .setLabel('PAPER')
                        .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                        .setDisabled(true),
                        new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('scissors-RPS')
                        .setLabel('SCISSORS')
                        .setStyle('SUCCESS')
                        .setDisabled(true))] 
                    })
                }
                if (interaction.customId == 'rock-RPS') {
                    if (botChoice == 'Rock') {
                        interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Rock too, so it's a tie!\nYou got \`$${reward1}\` as a small reward.`})
                        await db.set(`${interaction.user.id}.balance`, userBalance + reward1)
                    } else if (botChoice == 'Paper') {
                        interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Paper, so I win!`})
                    } else if (botChoice == 'Scissors') {
                        interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Scissors, so you win!\nYou got \`$${reward2}\` as an award!`})
                        await db.set(`${interaction.user.id}.balance`, userBalance + reward2)
                    }
                } else if (interaction.customId == 'paper-RPS') {
                    if (botChoice == 'Rock') {
                        interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Rock, so you win!\nYou got \`$${reward2}\` as an award!`})
                        await db.set(`${interaction.user.id}.balance`, userBalance + reward2)
                    } else if (botChoice == 'Paper') {
                        interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Paper too, so it's a tie!\nYou got \`$${reward1}\` as a small reward.`})
                        await db.set(`${interaction.user.id}.balance`, userBalance + reward1)
                    } else if (botChoice == 'Scissors') {
                        interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Scissors, so I win!`})
                    }
                } else if (interaction.customId == 'scissors-RPS') {
                    if (botChoice == 'Rock') {
                        interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Rock, so I win!`})
                    } else if (botChoice == 'Paper') {
                        interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Paper, so you win!\nYou got \`$${reward2}\` as an award!`})
                        await db.set(`${interaction.user.id}.balance`, userBalance + reward2)
                    } else if (botChoice == 'Scissors') {
                        interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Scissors too, so it's a tie!\nYou got \`$${reward1}\` as a small reward.`})
                        await db.set(`${interaction.user.id}.balance`, userBalance + reward1)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my answer to be a working correction of your original question. I have the `db` lines commented out for obvious reasons. You will just need to copy the new code in `bot` selections for PAPER and SCISSORS.

```
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.content === "!rps") {
        const buttonRow1 = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('rock-RPS')
                .setLabel('ROCK')
                .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                .setDisabled(false),
            new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('paper-RPS')
                .setLabel('PAPER')
                .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                .setDisabled(false),
            new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('scissors-RPS')
                .setLabel('SCISSORS')
                .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                .setDisabled(false)
        )
            
        const filter = (interaction) => {
            if (!interaction.isButton) return
            if (interaction.customId.includes('-RPS'))
            if (interaction.user.id === message.author.id) return true;
            
            interaction.reply({ content: 'This game isn\'t for you.' })
        }

        const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
            filter,
            max: 1,
        })

        // ******** CHANGE THIS LINE FROM .reply TO .send; ADD await to all sends/replies ********
        await message.channel.send({ embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setTitle('Let\'s Play!')], components: [buttonRow1] })
      
        const choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
            
        let botChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];

        // let userBalance =  parseInt(await db.fetch(`${message.author.id}.balance`))
            
        // if (userBalance == null) await db.set(`${message.author.id}.balance`, 0)
        
        function randomNumber(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min+1)+min);   
        }
        
        let reward1 = randomNumber(153, 535)
        let reward2 = randomNumber(553, 1460)

        collector.on('end', async (buttonInteraction) => {
            const interaction = buttonInteraction.first();
            const success = new MessageButton(buttonInteraction.component).setStyle("SUCCESS");
            
            if (interaction.customId == 'rock-RPS') {
                await interaction.update({ components: [new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
                    new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('rock-RPS')
                        .setLabel('ROCK')
                        .setStyle('SUCCESS')
                        .setDisabled(true),
                    new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('paper-RPS')
                        .setLabel('PAPER')
                        .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                        .setDisabled(true),
                    new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('scissors-RPS')
                        .setLabel('SCISSORS')
                        .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                        .setDisabled(true))] 
                })
            } else if (interaction.customId == 'paper-RPS') {
                await interaction.update({ components: [new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
                    new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('rock-RPS')
                        .setLabel('ROCK')
                        .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                        .setDisabled(true),
                    new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('paper-RPS')
                        .setLabel('PAPER')
                        .setStyle('SUCCESS')
                        .setDisabled(true),
                    new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('scissors-RPS')
                        .setLabel('SCISSORS')
                        .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                        .setDisabled(true))] 
                })
            } else if (interaction.customId == 'scissors-RPS') {
                await interaction.update({ components: [new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
                    new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('rock-RPS')
                        .setLabel('ROCK')
                        .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                        .setDisabled(true),
                    new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('paper-RPS')
                        .setLabel('PAPER')
                        .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                        .setDisabled(true),
                    new MessageButton()
                        .setCustomId('scissors-RPS')
                        .setLabel('SCISSORS')
                        .setStyle('SUCCESS')
                        .setDisabled(true))] 
                })
            }
            
            if (interaction.customId == 'rock-RPS') {
                if (botChoice == 'Rock') {
                    // ******** ADDED INDIVIDUAL STATES; DO FOR PAPER AND SCISSORS; THIS CAN BE GREATLY IMPROVED BUT IT GETS YOU GOING ********
                    const tie = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
                        new MessageButton()
                            .setCustomId('rock-RPS')
                            .setLabel('ROCK')
                            .setStyle('PRIMARY')
                            .setDisabled(true));
                    
                    await interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Rock too, so it's a tie!\nYou got \`$${reward1}\` as a small reward.`, components: [tie]})
                    
                    // await db.set(`${interaction.user.id}.balance`, userBalance + reward1)
                } else if (botChoice == 'Paper') {
                    const lose = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
                        new MessageButton()
                            .setCustomId('rock-RPS')
                            .setLabel('ROCK')
                            .setStyle('DANGER')
                            .setDisabled(true));
                            
                    await interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Paper, so I win!`, components: [lose]})
                } else if (botChoice == 'Scissors') {
                    const win = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
                        new MessageButton()
                            .setCustomId('rock-RPS')
                            .setLabel('ROCK')
                            .setStyle('SUCCESS')
                            .setDisabled(true));
                            
                    await interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Scissors, so you win!\nYou got \`$${reward2}\` as an award!`, components: [win]})
                    
                    // await db.set(`${interaction.user.id}.balance`, userBalance + reward2)
                }
            } else if (interaction.customId == 'paper-RPS') {
                if (botChoice == 'Rock') {
                    await interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Rock, so you win!\nYou got \`$${reward2}\` as an award!`})
                    
                    // await db.set(`${interaction.user.id}.balance`, userBalance + reward2)
                } else if (botChoice == 'Paper') {
                    await interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Paper too, so it's a tie!\nYou got \`$${reward1}\` as a small reward.`})
                    
                    // await db.set(`${interaction.user.id}.balance`, userBalance + reward1)
                } else if (botChoice == 'Scissors') {
                    await interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Scissors, so I win!`})
                }
            } else if (interaction.customId == 'scissors-RPS') {
                if (botChoice == 'Rock') {
                    await interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Rock, so I win!`})
                } else if (botChoice == 'Paper') {
                    await interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Paper, so you win!\nYou got \`$${reward2}\` as an award!`})
                    
                    // await db.set(`${interaction.user.id}.balance`, userBalance + reward2)
                } else if (botChoice == 'Scissors') {
                    await interaction.editReply({ content: `I chose Scissors too, so it's a tie!\nYou got \`$${reward1}\` as a small reward.`})
                    
                    // await db.set(`${interaction.user.id}.balance`, userBalance + reward1)
                }
            }
        })
                // }
            // })
        // }
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: I changed the code to fix some bugs

Comment: However, when I try your way, it makes an error... { The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.} or {Interaction has already been acknowledged.} if I remove the defer and change `editReply` to `reply`

Comment: Right, if you also have a way to allow me to disable them too would be great.

Comment: Sorry, updated it again, I just get an error {The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.}

Comment: Well, that is indeed strange because I copied your code exactly into my bot and it runs just fine (removing the `db` calls obviously). Here is a [link](https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=942771843478220871&permissions=2048&scope=bot) to add my bot to your server, if you want to try it? All it has in it is your code. One other thing, I am not using `module.exports`, just a regular `client.on('messageCreate')` event. As simple as possible. I don't think it matters, but which version of discord.js are you running?

Comment: I'm using 13v for the first time, so I didn't bother to make a command handler, however, my goal is simple, to learn how to make the bot change the clicked button into green without changing anything else, maybe it's not that simple after all, so yeah, I guess discord was kinda dumb not to add a small thing explaining how ".update()" works, I realized your code wasn't really what I meant, but you still tried, so I'll give you the points, however, I've tried a lot of ways, but none of them worked, maybe I'm just bad, or dumb, if you can help please direct message me. (Hamoodiyt#4822)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. It is frustrating for sure. However, I just realized your question wasn't about the logic not working, it was about changing the color. I totally spaced out on that. My apologies. The "game" worked, but you're right, the buttons did NOT change color. No reason to award any points, but I'll let you know if I find something.

Comment: It's ok, we all make mistakes, anyway, you still tried to help so you get the points anyway.

Comment: @Hamoodiyoutube I got it! Works like a champ now. See updated code.

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm! (For some reason that reminded me of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1e8UC8Cjcc) xD)